# Parameters Not working

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, reporting-services

im having issues with my parameters 
If i pass in 
a specific thing

i.e

```
@Sdate=01-01-2014, @edate =07-01-2014, @bd = Hobson, @CG= 01,02,03,04
```

i get data and everything works perfect

if i pass in

```
@Sdate=01-01-2014, @edate =07-01-2014, @bd = Hobson,Jerry,garry,bob,james @CG= 01,02,03,04
```

i get nothing not even hobsons data

before you ask my parameters passing multiple conditions are already set in

```
in (@parameterName)
```

Comment: Including your full SQL would perhaps help identify the problem

Comment: Your code posted here doesn't work because they don't have single tick marks. But I suspect the problem is you are trying use a comma delimited list as part of an IN clause. You can't do that. You have to parse those delimited values first or better yet, pass in a table value parameter. Here is an article explaining how to split your delimited values. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: this is example data not intended to follow syntax of how it should be passed in, i know everything is passing in how its suppose to, @SeanLange

Comment: @MiguelH unfortunatly i cant do that as work thinks its a security risk

Comment: I assumed that your code was just sample. You need to read the rest of my comment because you can't do this they way you are trying to.

Comment: How about just the WHERE clause?

Comment: @SeanLange your brilliant it was comma delimited please submit this as an answer so i can rate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is you are trying use a comma delimited list as part of an IN clause. You can't do that. You have to parse those delimited values first or better yet, pass in a table value parameter. Here is an article explaining how to split your delimited values.

http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings